# Getting interval from another table to pass to INTERVAL of another table in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

How to pass the interval from another `table(t2)` to a `date` of another `table(t1)` in query like this

```
SELECT CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL 'interval from t2'
```

Comment: got it ..based on this sqlines.com/postgresql/how-to/dateadd  i can use SELECT CURRENT_DATE +(select interval from t2) * INTERVAL '1 day'

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say since you didn't show your tables structure. But you should be familiar with the concept of joining tables to do this. Here is an example:

```
CREATE TABLE t1(
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    my_date DATE);

CREATE TABLE t2(
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    t1_id INTEGER REFERENCES t1(id),
    my_interval INTERVAL);
```

Then the query could be like this:

```
SELECT t1.my_date + t2.my_interval
FROM t1
JOIN t2 ON t2.t1_id = t1.id;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply...anywayi got it .by this sqlines.com/postgresql/how-to/dateadd where i can use SELECT CURRENT_DATE +(select interval from t2) * INTERVAL '1 day'

Comment: Could you show your table structure and the result you want to get?